# Passing QString variables between QDialog forms

Tags: c++, qt4, qstring, qdialog

The problem I have encountered is a bit trickier and not similar to other problems / solutions over the net. To provide a brief idea of my application, the work-flow is shown below;

[image]

I have done till fetching the data in Dialog2 and saved the data in `QString` variables. And I want to pass this back to Dialog1 **which is already OPEN**. Using these values I will do `setText` to set values to `QLabel` and `QLineEdit` widgets in Dialog1.

The technique I have used is not reflecting the changes on the Dialog1. Maybe because it is already OPEN and has not been updated.

Relevant code snippets are shown below -

**Dialog1.h**

```
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();    //this slot for pushbutton open Dialog2
public:
    void setLabelText(QString str);    //for setting the text of label
```

**Dialog1.cpp**

```
void Dialog1::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Dialog2 dialog2;
    dialog2.setModal(true);
    dialog2.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog2.exec();
}
void Dialog1::setLabelText(QString str)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(str);
    qDebug()<<"Value Arrived "<<str;
}
```

**Dialog2.h**

```
public slots:
    void saveSettings();    //slot for button press at dialog2, this will set the values at dialog1 and close the dialog2
```

**Dialog2.cpp**

```
void Dialog2::saveSettings()
{
    Dialog1 dialog1;
    dialog1.setLabelText(Vehicle_Name);       //Vehicle_Name is QString variable
    qDebug()<<"Sent Value "<<Vehicle_Name;
    accept();
}
```

The QString is getting passed properly between the QDialog form classes. I have used qDebug() messages to verify this.

How to ensure that the values of variables are reflected on Dialog1 ??? Can anyone please guide me with reference to my code ???

Comment: I think you should update dialog1 only when dialog2 is closed. You can do that by connecting `accepted()` signal of dialog2 to a slot. Also why do you call `dialog1.exec()` again in `Dialog2::saveSettings()`?

Comment: oopsie.. thats a mistake while copy pasting.. just a sec... and regarding to "how to update dialog1 after dialog2 is closed" that is where i am stuck at, any ideas ???

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear enough. Instead of calling `dialog1.setLabelText(Vehicle_Name)`, store `Vehicle_Name` in a variable. Maybe in a public member of `Dialog2`. Then connect `Dialog2::accepted()` signal to a slot of dialog1, something named `on_dialog2_accepted()`. In `on_dialog2_accepted()` make this call; `dialog1.setLabelText(dialog2.Vehicle_Name);`. `on_dialog2_accepted()` should be called when dialog2 is closed, and dialog1 will update itself. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialog2 should simply provide a signal containing the data you want to transfer to Dialog1 that gets emitted whenever Dialog2 is done with its action:

**Dialog1.cpp**

```
void Dialog1::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Dialog2 dialog2;
    dialog2.setModal(true);
    dialog2.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    connect(&dialog2, &Dialog2::dataFetched, this, &Dialog1::updateData);
    // or Qt4 connect syntax
    // connect(&dialog2, SIGNAL(dataFetched(const QString&)), this, SLOT(updateData(const QString&));
    // or directly connect to the label
    // connect(&dialog2, &Dialog2::dataFetched, ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::setText);
    dialog2.exec();
}

void Dialog1::updateData(const QString& data)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(data);
}
```

**Dialog2.h**

```
public slots:
    void saveSettings();    //slot for button press at dialog2, this will set the values at dialog1 and close the dialog2

signals:
    void dataFetched(const QString& data);
```

**Dialog2.cpp**

```
void Dialog2::saveSettings()
{
    // do whatever to generate the data
    emit dataFetched(Vehicle_Name);
    accept();
}
```

Comment: thanx, passing variables has been much more simplified now.

Answer (score 1):

`Dialog2` needs to know the **instance** of `Dialog1` where it was opened from, so it can pass the string back to this specific instance:

```
class Dialog1;
class Dialog2 : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog2(Dialog1* parent) : QDialog(parent), parent(parent) {}
public slots:
    void saveSettings()
    {
          parent->setLabelText("hello")
    }
private:
    Dialog1* parent;
};
```

Comment: sorry for my lack of expertise, having a hard time to understand where you are doing all these changes. It seems some are in .h and some in .cpp; can you please clear it out a little more ?

Comment: for simplicity I put all the code in the header, but of course you can move the method implementations into the cpp file. The important thing is that you pass a pointer to the `Dialog1` instance on to the `Dialog2` instance and store this pointer (`parent`) in order to be able to pass data back from `Dialog2` to `Dialog1`.

Comment: Dialog2 should never be tightly coupled to Dialog1 like this. This just asks for trouble in the long term, when you e.g. want to show Dialog2 from another context.